# google calendar inside android application

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar, mono

I need google calendar inside my applications, especially daily view.

Is there any widget, or some ready code to use or I should create my own?

I mean the same design and functionality as in the image below

[image]

Comment: One way: You could embed one of the Google's calendar's widgets in your app by becoming a "Widget Host" application, but your code would not interact with the widget directly, but with the "Calendar Provider" to query/add/delete to the appriotate calendar (since users can have multi-Google based ones and non-Google ones), then changes made via your app would 'sync' to the widget and be reflected in the widget embedded within your app just as they would be if that widget was placed on the android desktop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the google calendar in your app is not possible.

You can try to implement some calendar components but that will probably not give you the full control you want so you are better of creating your own and then implementing the Google Calendar API into your project: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

Edit: As RobertN said a widget might be possible but no interaction would be available making it fully integrated in your app.

Answer (score 1):

There in no way to use it in your application.

EDIT: RobertN described it exactly in the comment.